# Order issue between JRE and dependencies while compiling a Maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have compilation errors because the compiler is taking a class from a dependant library instead of the one in the JRE.
The class is defined in both libraries but I don't know how to stablish the preferred order.

I can do in Eclipse: Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export and there reorder them. But when the Eclipse Plugin for Maven builds again the project this order is lost.

If I exclude the interferring subdependency the problem goes away, but I'm not sure that it will not produce execution errors in the future.

Is there any way to fix the order between the JRE and the dependencies (using Maven I guess)?

**EDIT**
The class `javax.xml.XMLConstants` is defined in both the `JDK` libraries and in `stax-api` library (which is a dependency of `jasperreports` which I need). The Eclipse's compiler sais that `javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI`doesn't exist which is true for the one declared in `stax-api` but actually exists in the `JDK`.
I want that the compiler looks for that class in the JDK in the first place.

Comment: Note that even if the compiler looks for the right class, you still need to be sure that your runtime classpath is right or jasperreports will break when it needs its copy of XMLConstants.

Comment: Maybe this is a no solution issue but update libraries.

Comment: Yes.  Your libraries are too old for the Java version you are using.  The "java." namespace is reserved for the JVM itself.

Answer (score 0):

In maven you can user `<exclusion>` tag to exclude specific transitive dependency. Like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>sample.ProjectD</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-D from Project-B -->
            <artifactId>Project-D</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: As I said I know this possibility but I don't consider it right (I'm not sure that the dependency is totally ignorable).

Comment: You probably can exclude only one class via Shade Plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html), but from my perspective it's not a good way.
From my experience your problem is that you have one dependency in `CLASSPATH` with different versions. It it right (you can check it via `mvn dependency:tree`)?

Comment: It's strange. I've checked `stax-api` and it doesn't container `javax.xml.XMLContants`. Take a look http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/1.0-2/.

Comment: This is from 2006.  Are you sure you are using the newest artifacts?

Comment: As far as I see the version of byte code in this jar (stax-api-1.0.1.jar) is 1.3 so probably it's a problem because `javax.xml.XMLConstants` class has been introduced in Java 1.5.